# A word related to idling

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes government officials take an awful lot of time to process a certain file. Or students working on research problems may sit on a problem for long without making any meaningful progress. Could someone suggest a word for the same, say a replacement for 'sit on'? I have a few examples here:

1) Prof to student: Don't **__** on this problem for long, you may end up at a cul-de-sac.

2) You have been ***_*** and delaying my file for too long, please process it with urgency.

Comment: No single word occurs to me but *holding (on to)* should fit most situations: "Don't *hold on to* this problem for long"; "You have been *holding* my file for too long".

Comment: What's wrong with the two words in the question? "Idle" and "sit on"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second example, one might use one of

- *[trifle with](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+trifle+with)*, "to play the fool with; to treat without respect or seriousness; to mock"
- *[thumb-twiddle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumb_twiddling)*; "the thumbs circle around a common focal point", "thumb twiddling is frequently used as an example of a useless, time-wasting activity"
- *sit on*, or *[sit on hands](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sit+on+hands)*, idiom, "To fail to act"  [edit: I see "sit on" is in question already]
- *[dally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dally)*, "To delay unnecessarily; to while away" or *[dilly-dally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilly-dally)*, "to [dawdle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dawdle); to waste time; to procrastinate"
- *[procrastinate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/procrastinate)*, "To put off; to delay taking action; to wait until later. "

Some of the above but not all apply to the first example too.

I've also heard the term *[goldbricking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goldbrick)* used of bureaucrats, but from the definition "shirking or malingering" it may be an imperfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

Colloquial terms would include 'dillydally' and 'dawdle.' A term I don't hear very often anymore but that works well is 'tarry.'

Comment: I don't believe ;dilly-dally' is is a colloquial phrase. It's a highly colorful expression used to somehow imply a 'feminine'-type of irresoluteness to the person who is dallying. It is very rare to hear, but when it is spoken it is instantly understood. This was a common phrase used by crew chiefs on 'slicks' (troop-carrying helicopters in the Viet Nam conflict to hurry along the unloading process at the landing zone....usually with a four-letter word tacked on at the end (e.g, 'let's go ladies...no dilly-dally, s#@t!'

Answer (score 1):

When the act of delaying a process is intended it's called **stalling** and the verb is **to stall**. It can be both transitive or intransitive.

However, for 1) I'd rather use other alternatives as there seems to be no intention of deliberately stalling there.

[TFD:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Stalling)

> v.tr.
>   1. To put or lodge in a stall.
>   2. To maintain in a stall for fattening: to stall cattle.
>   **3. To halt the motion or progress of; bring to a standstill**.
>   4. To cause (a motor or motor vehicle) accidentally to stop running.
>   5. To cause (an aircraft) to go into a stall.
>   v.intr.
>   1. To live or be lodged in a stall. Used of an animal.
>   2. To stick fast in mud or snow.
>   **3. To come to a standstill: Negotiations stalled.**
>   4. To stop running as a result of mechanical failure: The car stalled on the freeway.
>   5. To lose forward flying speed, causing a stall. Used of an aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

I like "get stuck on" personally.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  **spend time**. It is more  neutral.